# Connection to 2nd monitor via DP is recognized but doesn't display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, displayport

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on an X1 Carbon with two Dell monitors connected via DisplayPort.

I've historically connected monitor 1 via DP and monitor 2 via HDMI without issue, but recently swapped out the HDMI for DP to allow connections to a second machine.

I've checked that connections are secure and see the second monitor recognized within the Displays menu but nothing is projected to the second screen (and I don't even get 'scanning' indications at any point).

[image]
[image]

Have tried a couple fixes (eg, waking up monitor manually via `xrandr`, turning display on and off) without success.

Can anyone shed some light to what may be going on?

**Edit** (updated with output of `xrandr` and addl details):

```
chris@chris-x1c6:~$ xrandr -q | grep DP
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
DP-1-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
```

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad dock that my X1 Carbon is locked into.  DP output 1 on the dock is going to DP input 1 on the 1st monitor; DP output 2 is going to DP input 1 on the 2nd monitor.

The monitor that's showing nothing never displays anything (ie, no 'No signal' message at any point), this is even though it's being picked up per the Displays settings (images included previously).

Comment: Can you update your question with the full results of `xrandr` and also clarify exactly your connections/cables on the PC and monitors. e.g. is it now PC side DP output to Monitor DP input for both monitors? Or are you using adaptors or anything like that? The monitor that does not show anything, is it showing "No Signal" or just showing nothing but it's on/awake? Or does it show nothing and goes into sleep/standby?

Comment: @codlord, updated with requested detail.

Comment: Now you mention a dock I suspect it's the reason for your issues. From what I have seen/read Ubuntu and monitors direct seem to just work but people using docks/adaptors have mixed results. Perhaps it's because the docks arey designed for Windows and have relevant Windows drivers so don't always play nice with Ubuntu? All I can suggest is searching here for previous topics involving DP/HDMI and docks or trying a newer version of Ubuntu?